# Python: calculate character frequencies in word list effectively

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, counter, frequency

When I have a long list like

```
words = ['axcd', 'abcd', 'abef', 'abxf']
```

where each string has the same length, how do I calculate an array like

```
result[0] = [{char: 'a', freq: 4}] 
result[1] = [{char: 'b', freq: 3}, {char: 'x', freq: 1}] # ordered by frequencies
result[2] = [{char: 'c', freq: 2}, {char: 'e', freq: 1}, {char: 'x', freq: 1}]
result[3] = [{char: 'd', freq: 2}, {char: 'f', freq: 2}]
```

in the most effective way ?

Comment: Does the result have to be a list like `[{char: 'b', freq: 3}, {char: 'x', freq: 1}]`? Why not an `OrderedDict(b=3, x=1)` instead?

Comment: make an attempt before asking, SO is not a coding service

Comment: @Aran-Fey An OrderedDict would also be good

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? Feel free to accept one, or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using `collections.Counter` and `zip`.

I have explicitly defined a `formatter` function for clarity.

```
from collections import Counter

words = ['axcd', 'abcd', 'abef', 'abxf']

def formatter(res):
    return [{'char': k, 'freq': v} for k, v in sorted(res.items(),
            key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]

result = dict(enumerate(formatter(Counter(i)) for i in zip(*words)))
```

Result:

```
{0: [{'char': 'a', 'freq': 4}],
 1: [{'char': 'b', 'freq': 3}, {'char': 'x', 'freq': 1}],
 2: [{'char': 'c', 'freq': 2}, {'char': 'e', 'freq': 1}, {'char': 'x', 'freq': 1}],
 3: [{'char': 'd', 'freq': 2}, {'char': 'f', 'freq': 2}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Transpose the input list with the old `zip(*words)` trick
2. Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the letters in each row
3. Sort the counters' elements by value
4. Turn the sorted elements into [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)s

```
import collections
import operator

words = ['axcd', 'abcd', 'abef', 'abxf']

transposed = zip(*words)
counts = [collections.Counter(letters) for letters in transposed]
sorted_counts = [sorted(dic.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
                       for dic in counts]
result = [collections.OrderedDict(items) for items in sorted_counts]

# result:
# [OrderedDict([('a', 4)]),
#  OrderedDict([('b', 3), ('x', 1)]),
#  OrderedDict([('c', 2), ('e', 1), ('x', 1)]),
#  OrderedDict([('d', 2), ('f', 2)])]
```

---

To give some more insight into what each step does, I'll post the intermediate results here.

After transposing the input, it looks like this:

```
>>> transposed
[('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
 ('x', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
 ('c', 'c', 'e', 'x'),
 ('d', 'd', 'f', 'f')]
```

These tuples are then turned into Counters:

```
>>> counts
[Counter({'a': 4}),
 Counter({'b': 3, 'x': 1}),
 Counter({'c': 2, 'e': 1, 'x': 1}),
 Counter({'d': 2, 'f': 2})]
```

Sorting these turns them into lists of `(key, value)` tuples:

```
>>> sorted_counts
[[('a', 4)],
 [('b', 3), ('x', 1)],
 [('c', 2), ('e', 1), ('x', 1)],
 [('d', 2), ('f', 2)]]
```

And in the last step they're converted to OrderedDicts.

Comment: Nice. Similar to mine except you apply `OrderedDict` instead of `dict(enumerate(...))`. +1